# MongoDB- could not find member to sync from

Tags: mongodb

Node logs under Recovery mode, even after restarting:

> 2018-04-24T12:37:52.915+0530 I REPL     [replication-0] We are too
>   stale to use J-DB-02:27017 as a sync source. Blacklisting this sync
>   source because our last fetched timestamp: 5ade01e0:66 is before their
>   earliest timestamp: 5aded094:198 for 1min until:
>   2018-04-24T12:38:52.915+0530
>       2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL     [replication-0] could not find member to sync from
>       2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 E REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] too stale to catch up -- entering maintenance mode
>       2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Our newest OpTime : { ts: Timestamp 1524498912000|102, t: 68 }
>       2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Earliest OpTime available is { ts: Timestamp 1524551828000|408, t: 68
>   }
>       2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/resyncingaverystalereplicasetmember
>       2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] going into maintenance mode with 0 other maintenance mode tasks in progress
>       2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] transition to RECOVERING

Here is the status of replica set from primary server

```
WAPRS01:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.stats().maxSize
WAPRS01:PRIMARY> rs.status();
{
        "set" : "WAPRS01",
        "date" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:15.276Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(68),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1524498912, 102),
                        "t" : NumberLong(68)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1524554235, 160),
                        "t" : NumberLong(68)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1524554235, 92),
                        "t" : NumberLong(68)
                }
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "J-DB-01:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 3,
                        "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
                        "uptime" : 569,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1524498912, 102),
                                "t" : NumberLong(68)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1524498912, 102),
                                "t" : NumberLong(68)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-23T15:55:12Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-04-23T15:55:12Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:13.532Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:13.493Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "configVersion" : 4
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "J-DB-02:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 299382,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1524554232, 270),
                                "t" : NumberLong(68)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1524554232, 270),
                                "t" : NumberLong(68)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:12Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:12Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:13.454Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:13.864Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "syncingTo" : "J-DB-03:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 4
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "J-DB-03:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 613420,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1524554235, 160),
                                "t" : NumberLong(68)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:15Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1524254862, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-04-20T20:07:42Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 4,
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "J-DB-04:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 300361,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:14.863Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:14.229Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "configVersion" : 4
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
WAPRS01:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**